# Episerver7 MultipleProperty implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver, episerver-7

Could you help me with MultiProperty implementation on EPi7. I've tried to do it just like on version 6R2 but with no luck. I'm getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when trying to edit the property. This is the declaration:

```
[CultureSpecific]
        [Editable(true)]
        [Display(
            Name = "test ",
            Description = "test",
            GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
            Order = 100)]
        [BackingType(typeof(PropertyTestCategories))]
        public virtual TestCategories test { get; set; }
```

Comment: The old way of creating custom properties should still work in EPiServer CMS 7 (using popup window for displaying the custom property control). You should provide more information about the error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do exactly, but a local block (i.e. a property with its type set to a block type) might allow you to do a "composite property" if that's what you're aiming for?